# 'this' inside event listener callback overrides 'this' class

Tags: javascript, class, events, this

What is the best way to structure the following code?

I have a part of code on client side that is responsible for communicating with a PHP server. It is sending some data to it, the server then based on type of request modifies the database or just retrieves some data from it which it then sends back to the client as a response.

My first idea was to encapsulate client code in a class named `Foo`. It would open the connection inside of its constructor. When upper layer wanted to request data modification or retrieval it would call one of many `Foo` methods which would prepare and send a request to PHP server via `this.#httpRequest.send()`. Once `Foo` received a response it would extract the relevant data and call the upper layer provided callback function `this.onReceiveOk`.

An example code and problem:

```
class Foo {
    #httpRequest;
    onReceiveOk;

    constructor() {
        this.#httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.#httpRequest.addEventListener('load', this.#handleLoad);
    }

    #handleLoad() {
        this.onReceiveOk(this.#httpRequest.responseText); // ERROR: 'onReceiveOk' is not a function
    }
}
```

However I noticed that when method `#handleLoad` is called the context for `this` is no longer `Foo` class. I did some googling and found that in this case the context is the calling function, so the `XMLHttpRequest` class.

Is there a way to make the context of `#handleLoad` be `Foo` class? Is this code structuring the standard way or should I change something about it? Should I use closures instead of classes for this particular case? I have used class so that code is modular and I can import the class in upper layer.

Comment: modern solution would be `this.#httpRequest.addEventListener('load', e => this.#handleLoad(e));` (didn't see that in the accepted answer on the duplicate)